# Preloader Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Como eu posso fazer um preloader(carregando...) enquanto ele está rendenizando a view no `@RenderBody` ?

Em busca apenas achei exemplos usando Partial, mas Views não

Alguma ideia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tem muito segredo:

### Controller

```
public JsonResult MinhaAction(int id)
{
    // Preenchimento de 'meuJson', e tal
    return Json(meuJson);
}
```

### View

Estou usando jQuery, e supondo que você já achou uma tela de "carregando" em algum lugar. Vou supor que ela fica dentro de uma `<div>` cujo Id é "carregando":

```
$('#meuLink').click(function()
{
    var action = '@Html.ResolveUrl("~/MeuController/MinhaAction/")' + $('#campoId').val();
    $('#carregando').show()
    $.getJSON(action, null, function(variavelDeCallback) 
    {
        // Faça aqui o que precisa com 'meuJson'
        $('#carregando').hide()
    });
});
```

Comment: Aí é um retorno Json cigano, eu queria a página toda return View()

Comment: @Rod Isto é um comportamento feito por JavaScript. Aí depende de como sua View é chamada. Se for por Ajax, minha resposta serve. Caso contrário, não sei se tem como fazer.

Comment: é chamada com actionlink mesmo

Comment: @Rod como o Cigano falou desde que o link seja carregado por ajax não tem problema ser View ou PartialView, claro que sendo View, por padrão, o LayoutMaster virá junto e você pode dar replace de tudo (o que não acho boa ideia) ou então na view remover o LayoutMaster!